# Monodevelop 4.0.12 on debian - C console project do not debug

Tags: c, linux, debugging, monodevelop

I saw in a Monodevelop official site is possible to debug a C project (feature list) on linux. I'm working on a debian jessie but the debugging mode is always grey (disabled). Why this?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide more info: which site, what is disabled, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Maybe I find out that plugin GNU Debugger for MonoDevelop is not available yet for debian jessie. Is this the problem?